# when to use use_ssl in http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ssl, https

I am making an HTTP connection to the URL. When I use `http.use_ssl=false` it does not work and the response is 400 error. When I use `http.use_ssl=true` it works. why is that?

```rb
          url = "https://beta.makaan-ws.com/"
          uri = URI.parse(url)
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.request_uri)
          headers.each do |header_key, header_val|
            request.add_field(header_key, header_val)
          end
          request.body = post_args.to_json
          begin
            response = http.request(request)
          rescue
            raise "Error from url: #{url}"
          end
```

I want to understand the role of `use_ssl`? Do we have to assign true when URL is if https type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes, usually it is used like this:

```rb
http.use_ssl = url.scheme == 'https'
```

TCP port is different for HTTP and HTTPS:

```rb
URI.parse("http://example.com").port # => 80
URI.parse("https://example.com").port # => 443
```

But in general, any protocol can be used on any port number and there's no reliable way for transport lib to know which protocol to use. For example, you can easily configure your server to answer with plain http on port 443 and vice versa.

That's why here's `use_ssl`, it indicates to http library that connection to that port should be made using TLS/TLS secure connection and not a plain non-encrypted one.

Comment: but I have assigned the port before assigning ssl=true.

Comment: and why ssl=false cannot make a connection?

Comment: @code0079 port number does not guarantee protocol, with `use_ssl=false` it will try to connect with plain http to a ssl port (and that will sound greek to the server)